# Reset ONLY bootstrapvalidator in modal form

Tags: javascript, java, validation, bootstrap-4

How to reset ONLY bootstrapValidator errors from form. I dont want to delete all data from form, data from input fields. I just want to delete errors from bootstrapvalidator. 
$('#form').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true); -> THIS DOESNT WORK THIS DELETE ALL DATA FROM MY FORM. Thanks

Comment: [Please format code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
    var bootstrapValidator = $('#form').data('bootstrapValidator');

    // and then call method
    bootstrapValidator.destroy();
```

Comment: That refresh my page.